# Are move constructors produced automatically?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

I have a big class holding a lot of STL containers.
Will the compiler automatically make a move constructor that will move those containers to the target or I have to make my own?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A move constructor for a class X is implicitly declared as defaulted exactly when

> - X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
> - the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

So for example, if your class has a class type data member that does not have a move constructor, your class will not get a move constructor even if it doesn't have any copy/move constructor declared, because the implicitly declared move constructor would be defined as deleted (because of that data member).

Comment: Interestingly, a user-declared move-constructor does not prevent the compiler from implicitly declaring a copy constructor. Maybe, that is worth mentioning here. At least this is what http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html says.

Comment: It's interesting that **all** members are required to have a move constructor.  It seems sane to move all the members that can be moved and copy the ones that can't.

Comment: So the best shot is to define move ctor for yourself, don't rely on compiler.

Comment: And the said class member would not have an implicit move constructor because one or more of the items in the above list was not met.

Comment: @KevinCox It is common to guarantee that a move constructor does not throw an exception, while a copy constructor often can (e.g. out of memory), so this might not be a good idea. You could argue "that's ok, the implicit move constructor just wouldn't be noexcept" but I still think there's potential for surprise (i.e. bugs).

Comment: So, if I move a class that doesn't have automatically generated move constructor, then automatically generated copy constructor is used? :/

Comment: It's probably better to use explicitly defaulted move constructors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290523/is-a-default-move-constructor-equivalent-to-a-member-wise-move-constructor

Answer (score 4):

Default move constructors are generally tied to default copy constructors. You get one when you get the other. However, if you write a copy constructor/assignment operator, then no default copy *and* move constructors/assignment operators are written. If you write one of either set, you must write them all.

Comment: According to cppreference, an implicit copy constructor is provided even if you have an explicit move constructor by the user.