# Will C++ use a move constructor from a copy assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

Say I have a simple struct that contains a vector and defines a copy assignment operator, and a function that returns this struct, like so:

```
struct SimpleStruct
{
    vector< int > vec1;

    operator=( SimpleStruct& other )
    {
         vec1 = other.vec1;
    }
}

SimpleStruct GetStruct();
```

As I understand it, because I've declared a copy assignment operator, the compiler won't automatically generate a move constructor for SimpleStruct.

So if I use the `GetStruct` function like this:

```
SimpleStruct value = GetStruct();
```

Is the compiler smart enough to move rather than copy the vector when I say `vec1 = other.vec1;`?  Or will I need to explicitly define a move constructor/assignment operator for SimpleStruct to take advantage of a vector move?

Comment: It cannot move anything from `other` when that is `const`.

Comment: @BoPersson Ah, didn't think of that.  Removed the const for the sake of the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, the compiler won't automatically generate a move constructor or assignment operator in any scenario. They always have to be provided by the developer, if move semantics are desired.

Comment: @dauphic Are you sure about that?  This question seems to disagree:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283589/are-move-constructors-produced-automatically

Comment: I may be wrong, and I'm not going to argue with litb, but I just tested and a POD wasn't provided with one.

Comment: PODs do get move constructors, although there is no direct way to tell, since the move constructor for a POD does the same thing as the copy constructor for a POD.  Note: one way to indirectly tell is by using type_traits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 has very strict rules about when movement is allowed to happen. And unless a temporary is involved, those rules require the explicit use of `std::move` or a similar cast (such as `std::forward` in some cases).

Yes, you *could* move something. But it wouldn't happen by accident; it would have to be deliberate.

Also, it is generally rude to write a copy-assignment operator that can modify what is being copied. That's why they usually take a `const&`, which pretty much guarantees the inability to move.

> Or will I need to explicitly define a move constructor/assignment operator for SimpleStruct to take advantage of a vector move?

In general, this is why you *don't* explicitly define copy and move constructors. Let the compiler do it's job and generate those for you (unless you're using VC++ which doesn't do its job for move constructors/assignment). Only explicitly write copy/move constructors for lower-level containers; anything larger should just rely on those value types to do their jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a copy constructor or copy assignment operator, copy means copy. The language never makes any contextual adjustment to the contents of a function based on how it is called.

However, it's likely that no copy will occur in `SimpleStruct value = GetStruct();` because [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) applies.