# Is a `=default` move constructor equivalent to a member-wise move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default, move-semantics

Is this

```
struct Example { 
    string a, b; 

    Example(Example&& mE) : a{move(mE.a)}, b{move(mE.b)} { }
    Example& operator=(Example&& mE) { a = move(mE.a); b = move(mE.b); return *this; } 
}
```

equivalent to this

```
struct Example { 
    string a, b;

    Example(Example&& mE)            = default;
    Example& operator=(Example&& mE) = default;
}
```

?

Comment: This might be a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819936/why-no-default-move-assignment-move-constructor

Comment: @DieterLücking: It's clearly not, though it's on a similar topic and some answers may cover similar ground. However, we shall not close every single question about move semantics as duplicates of each other.

Comment: Note, I added my answer to this question because at the time I was looking for a quote from the standard that proved they were equivalent and the accepted answer does not do that. So, I just found the quote and added my answer.

Comment: I also want to mention, that in your Example the _default constructor_ is **not declared** and the _destructor_ is **defaulted** - See [Howard Hinnant - compiler implicit declares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2EUm.png)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Yes both are the same.**

But

```
struct Example { 
    string a, b; 

    Example(Example&& mE)            = default;
    Example& operator=(Example&& mE) = default;
}
```

This version will permits you to skip the body definition.

However, you have to follow some rules when you declare `explicitly-defaulted-functions` :

> **8.4.2 Explicitly-defaulted functions [dcl.fct.def.default]**
>
> A function definition of the form:
>
> ```
>   attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt decl-speciﬁer-seqopt declarator virt-speciﬁer-seqopt = default ;
> ```
>
> is called an *explicitly-defaulted* definition. A function that is explicitly defaulted shall
>
> - be a special member function,
> - have the same declared function type (except for possibly differing *ref-qualifiers* and except that in the case of a copy constructor or copy assignment operator, the parameter type may be “reference to non-const `T`”, where `T` is the name of the member function’s class) as if it had been implicitly declared,
> - not have default arguments.

Comment: What document are you quoting 8.4.2 from? Neither the C++11 standard or N3690 contain the text ", and not have an *exception-specification*" in 8.4.2/1. They do both say in 8.4.2/2: "An explicitly-defaulted function may be declared `constexpr` only if it would have been implicitly declared as `constexpr`, and may have an explicit *exception-specification* only if it is compatible (15.4) with the *exception-specification* on the implicit declaration."

Comment: @Casey Good catch ! I was quoting the N3242... I mixed up my docs... I updated my post to quote the N3690 ! Thank you for pointing this out !

Comment: If I set a move constructor and assignment operator to `= default`, will I be able to swap with the object? Don't I need to declare the constructor as `noexcept`? I tried putting both `noexcept` and `=default` for both, but this would not compile.

Comment: Declaring copy constructor or assignment or destructor prevents default move constructor generation. If we define any of these functions,we have to define move constructor. But how about the case copy constructor is defined but move constructor is created by default keyword.Does it work as expected?

Comment: Are they the same even if `Example` inherits some class?

Answer (score 45):

> Is a `=default` move constructor equivalent to a member-wise move constructor?

<s>Yes</s>. **Update:** Well, not always. Look at this example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct nonmovable
{
    nonmovable() = default;

    nonmovable(const nonmovable  &) = default;
    nonmovable(      nonmovable &&) = delete;
};

struct movable
{
    movable() = default;

    movable(const movable  &) { std::cerr << "copy" << std::endl; }
    movable(      movable &&) { std::cerr << "move" << std::endl; }
};

struct has_nonmovable
{
    movable    a;
    nonmovable b;

    has_nonmovable() = default;

    has_nonmovable(const has_nonmovable  &) = default;
    has_nonmovable(      has_nonmovable &&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    has_nonmovable c;
    has_nonmovable d(std::move(c)); // prints copy
}
```

It prints:

```
copy
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62c0a0aaec15b0eb

You declared defaulted move constructor, but copying happens instead of moving. Why? Because if a class has even a single non-movable member then the ***explicitly** defaulted* move constructor is ***implicitly** deleted* (such a pun). So when you run `has_nonmovable d = std::move(c)`, the copy constructor is actually called, because the move constructor of `has_nonmovable` is deleted (implicitly), it just doesn't exists (even though you explicitly declared the move constructor by expression `has_nonmovable(has_nonmovable &&) = default`).

But if  the move constructor of `non_movable` was not declared at all, the move constructor would be used for `movable` (and for every member that has the move constructor) and the copy constructor would be used for `nonmovable` (and for every member that does not define the move constructor). See the example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct nonmovable
{
    nonmovable() = default;

    nonmovable(const nonmovable  &) { std::cerr << "nonmovable::copy" << std::endl; }
    //nonmovable(      nonmovable &&) = delete;
};

struct movable
{
    movable() = default;

    movable(const movable  &) { std::cerr << "movable::copy" << std::endl; }
    movable(      movable &&) { std::cerr << "movable::move" << std::endl; }
};

struct has_nonmovable
{
    movable    a;
    nonmovable b;

    has_nonmovable() = default;

    has_nonmovable(const has_nonmovable  &) = default;
    has_nonmovable(      has_nonmovable &&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    has_nonmovable c;
    has_nonmovable d(std::move(c));
}
```

It prints:

```
movable::move
nonmovable::copy
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/420cc6c80ddac407

**Update:** But if you comment out the line `has_nonmovable(has_nonmovable &&) = default;`, then copy will be used for both members: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/171fd0ce335327cd - prints:

```
movable::copy
nonmovable::copy
```

So probably putting `=default` everywhere still makes sense. It doesn't mean that your move expressions will always move, but it makes chances of this higher.

**One more update:** But if comment out the line `has_nonmovable(const has_nonmovable &) = default;` either, then the result will be:

```
movable::move
nonmovable::copy
```

So if you want to know what happens in your program, just do everything by yourself :sigh:

Comment: The explicitly defaulted move constructor is *deleted* in your first example, because that's what an implicit move constructor would be. It is *overload resolution* that disambiguates between the copy and move when presented with an rvalue

Comment: The *result* of `has_nonmovable(has_nonmovable&&)= default` is a deleted move constructor, because of the `= delete`'d move constructor in a member. You ask for a move constructor that matches what would be generated by default, and get that.

Comment: @Caleth, ok, I understand now. But I'm not sure you are right. If the move constructor of `has_nonmovable` was deleted, the compilation would fail. See this link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f8c387cd45c0de1. The error there is: `use of deleted function`. I don't think that the result would be different if _C++_ had _**implicitly** deleted_ move constructors.

Comment: That's the difference between *deleted implicitly-declared* and *explicitly deleted*. When you explicitly delete a special member, it remains in the overload set, and the program is ill-formed if it would be selected. When it is implicitly deleted, it is removed from the overload set. See [Deleted implicitly-declared move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)

Comment: In your second example, `has_nonmovable(has_nonmovable&&)` does a memberwise move, and overload resolution only finds `nonmovable(const nonmovable &)` for `b`

Comment: @Caleth, Well, You are right most likely: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/064cada42675e388. Then that explains what happens in the first example.

Comment: @Caleth, but this means that an explicitly defaulted move constructor is not always _equivalent to a member-wise move constructor_ (the title of the current question). Sometimes _explicitly defaulted_ means just _implicitly deleted_.

Comment: If and only if the member wise move would be ill-formed, so I don't count it as different

Comment: @Caleth, But I do. For me, it would be better if a compiler just gave me the message: `cannot declare explicitly defaulted move constructor because it would be ill-formed`. Without this I just think that my **move**-expression moves when it is actually not a move expression at all because the move constructor was implicitly deleted by compiler. Explicit expression makes implicit things. This confuses very much.

Comment: Why oh why can't the compiler errors be more helpful. The language is becoming unusable by anyone outside the standards committee. The initialization rules alone are far too complex to keep in your head http://randomcat.org/cpp_initialization/initialization.png. The compiler should be surfacing these details in a helpful manner.

Comment: For anyone confused about why the second example prints `movable::move nonmovable::copy`, it's because "For non-union class types, the move constructor performs full member-wise move of the object's direct bases and non-static data members, in their initialization order, using direct initialization with an xvalue argument."([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-defined_move_constructor)). Basically, this means that the generated move constructor tries to construct each member by doing something similar to `member{std::move(other.member)}`...

Comment: ... where `other` is the parameter of the move constructor, so it's possible that that line selects the copy constructor if the move constructor is not defined, just like `nonmovable` in the second example.

Answer (score 34):

Yes, a defaulted move constructor will perform a member-wise move of its base and members, so:

```
Example(Example&& mE) : a{move(mE.a)}, b{move(mE.b)} { }
```

is equivalent to:

```
Example(Example&& mE)                 = default;
```

we can see this by going to the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `12.8` *Copying and moving class objects* paragraph *13* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> A copy/move constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted
>   **is implicitly defined** if it is odrused (3.2) or when it is explicitly
>   defaulted after its first declaration. [ Note: The copy/move
>   constructor is implicitly defined even if the implementation elided
>   its odr-use (3.2, 12.2). —end note ][...]

and paragraph *15* which says:

> The **implicitly-defined copy/move constructor** for a non-union class X
>   **performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members**. [ Note:
>   brace-or-equal-initializers of non-static data members are ignored.
>   See also the example in 12.6.2. —end note ] The order of
>   initialization is the same as the order of initialization of bases and
>   members in a user-defined constructor (see 12.6.2). Let x be either
>   the parameter of the constructor or, for the move constructor, an
>   xvalue referring to the parameter. Each base or non-static data member
>   is copied/moved in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> - if the member is an array, each element is direct-initialized with the corresponding subobject of x;
> - if a member m has rvalue reference type T&&, it is direct-initialized with static_cast(x.m);
> - otherwise, the base or member is direct-initialized with the corresponding base or member of x.
>
> Virtual base class subobjects shall be initialized only once by the
>   implicitly-defined copy/move constructor (see 12.6.2).

Answer (score -3):

apart very pathological cases ... YES.

To be more precise, you have also to considered eventual bases `Example` may have, with exact same rules. First the bases -in declaration order- then the members, always in declaration order.

Comment: But code cannot change the order of subobject construction. The language ignores the order of the constructor's member-initializer list and always constructs (and destructs) class subobjects in a consistent order. So changing that will not cause a constructor to not be equivalent.