# How is a default move constructor for a class with STL members defined?

Tags: c++, stl, move, move-semantics, move-constructor

I have searched this a little bit but couldn't find a similar example so I wanted to ask just to be sure. If I have a class with no explicit heap allocation but only STL classes like so:

```
class Klass {
..
private:
  vector<int> v;
};
```

Does default move constructor provide me the proper move semantics for free, that is something similar to `Klass(Klass&& other) : v(move(other.v)) { .. }`?

Comment: You may find this question useful: [Does a =default move constructor equals to a member-wise move constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18290523/1708801)

Comment: Yep, that's a duplicate

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour indeed I did, thanks..

Comment: Table of generated special members: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24512883/3747990