# Why is my defaulted move constructor not noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor, noexcept

According to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653726/is-the-default-move-constructor-defined-as-noexcept), a default move constructor can be defined as `noexcept` under certain conditions. For instance, the following class generates a `noexcept` move constructor:

```
class C {};
```

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660945/what-are-the-rules-for-noexcept-on-default-defined-move-constructors), a move constructor defined with the `= default` specifier would generate the same one as an implicitly defined move constructor. So, if I correctly understand it, the following class should generate a `noexcept` move constructor:

```
class D {
    D(D&&) = default;
};
```

To check that, I used the `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` function to see if `C` and `D` have a `noexcept` move constructor:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<C>::value, "C should be noexcept MoveConstructible");
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<D>::value, "D should be noexcept MoveConstructible");

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I get this error:

```
$ g++ toy.cpp -o toy
toy.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
toy.cpp:16:5: error: static assertion failed: D should be noexcept MoveConstructible
     static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<D>::value, "D should be noexcept MoveConstructible");
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is my `D` move constructor not `noexcept`?

---

I also tried with Clang and I get the same error. Here is the information about my compilers:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ clang++8 --version
clang version 8.0.0 
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In fact it has nothing to do with `noexcept`; `static_assert` would fail also with `std::is_move_constructible` because the move constructor is `private`. So just declare it as `public`.

```
class D {
public:
    D(D&&) = default;
};
```

[LIVE with Clang8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qhgXEwEKYa4lld2C)

Answer (score 13):

I believe the problem is that you defaulted move constructor of `D` is *private*. Try to make it **public**.