# If I delete the copy constructor, do I get no implicit move constructor?

Tags: c++

The following wont compile (tried both clang & gcc)

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int a=0) : m_a(a) {}
    Foo(const Foo& f) = delete;
    // Foo(Foo&& f) = default;
private:
    int m_a;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> foovec;
    foovec.emplace_back(44); // might resize, so might move
}
```

But if I don't delete the copy constructor, or if I default the move constructor, 
it will work. So, does deleting copy constructor suppress move constructor, 
and *what is the rational behind that*?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283589/are-move-constructors-produced-automatically

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Why does it need the copy or move-constructor when it is constructing a `Foo` in-place?

Comment: @0x499602D2: it's needed for vector resizing, there might be not enough space when you `emplace_back`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should see table about special class members. When you set copy constructor as a deleted one move constructor won't be generated automatically.

See more in table:

[image]

[Source (slides)](https://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf).