# Templated class constructor uses wrong overload when in struct

Tags: c++, templates

The test is as following:

```
class NotInit{};

NotInit NOT_INIT;

template<class T>
class Optional{

  T value;
  bool has_value;

public:
  Optional() : value(), has_value(false){}
  explicit Optional(NotInit):value(), has_value(false) {}
  explicit Optional(T const & val):value(val), has_value(true){}
  explicit Optional(Optional<T> const & other) {}

  Optional& operator=(Optional<T> const & other){}
  Optional& operator=(T const & other){}
};

enum X {
  FIRST
};

struct Some {
  Optional<X> member;
};

int main(int, char**){
  Optional<X> const opt(NOT_INIT);
  Some s = {NOT_INIT};
  return 0;
}
```

Clang 3.4 complains:

```
../st.cpp:31:12: error: no viable conversion from 'NotInit' to 'Optional<X>'
        Some s = {NOT_INIT};
                  ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Why does it complain for the struct initialization but ont for the varaiable? Why is it not choosing the constructor with the proper parameter?

What overload is missing so that i can use this to init the struct?

I cannot use boost and i'm not sure this error would not appear if using `boost::optional`.

Comment: Why did you define your copy constructor as `explicit`?

Comment: @Rerito that does not make any sense i'm sorry. I was just trying to build a working example.

Comment: You might find these useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283589/are-move-constructors-produced-automatically/8285499#8285499. I needed it to fully answer your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are marking your constructors `explicit`. Thus when you are trying to initialize your `struct Some` with a brace-initializer list, you are triggering an implicit conversion...

This is prevented here:

```cpp
class NotInit;
template <typename T>
class Optional {
    // Here => Optional(NotInit) cannot be called implicitly
    explicit Optional(NotInit):value(), has_value(false) {}
};
/* ... */
Some s = {NOT_INIT}; // Implicit call to Optional<X>(NotInit): whoops!
```

If you remove the `explicit`, you can keep:

```cpp
Some s = {NOT_INIT};
```

If you chose not to, then you'll have to instantiate `s` like this:

```cpp
Some s = {Optional<X>(NOT_INIT)};
```

In any case, you'll have to remove the `explicit` keyword on your copy constructor (which has to perform a copy and not be a "dummy" constructor).
Why? Because once the `Optional<X>` object is built from `NOT_INIT`, a copy has to be made to `s.member`.

*Note: You could also provide a move constructor, which would be more appropriate in that case, since the object you get from the conversion of `NOT_INIT`is an rvalue.*

Comment: @user2079303 Indeed it does. And not explicit ones. I guess you stated that because OP's copy constructor does nothing?

Comment: whoops I was a bit confused, yes there is copy constructor in the question, but I couldn't get it to compile unless I made both  `Optional(NotInit)` and the copy constructor non-explicit.