# How many constructors are in the person class above?

Tags: c++

Consider the implementation of the following class

```
class person {
private: 
 int age;
 int getAge();
 void setName(string);
public:
 string name;
 person(int , string);
 person(string);
 person();
 void setAge(int);
 string getName();
}
```

How many constructors are in the person class above?

```
1
2
3
7
?
```

Comment: You're either quizzing us or this is homework.

Comment: Is this is a counting puzzle?

Comment: Even worse would be if this is a take home exam...

Comment: @sdubs177 By the way I was the first who aswered correctly!

Comment: My hobby: _counting_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 or 5 constructors in `person`.
The 3 you defined yourself, plus the compiler-generated copy constructor.

If C++11 is used, specific rules determine whether or not a move constructor will be generated for you, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-ctor-copy-ctor-and-default-assi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283589/are-move-constructors-produced-automatically).

Comment: move constructor and move assignment are not automatically generated.

Comment: @NathanOliver Move constructors are automatically generated (under the right conditions) [Conditions for automatic generation of default ctor, copy ctor, and default assignment operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-ctor-copy-ctor-and-default-assi). The C++0x section states the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I counted five constructors because I have 5 fingers on my hand.:) However among possible answers

```
1
2
3
7
```

there is no answer with the number 5. So I am thinking whether it is only me who has 5 fingers on the hand or others can not count up to 5.:)

Comment: There are three kinds of people, those who can count, and the others ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42  The question does not ask to explain the selection. It only asks about the number of constructors.:)

Comment: Excellent joke-missing!