# std::move on std::optional of type std::vector

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it safe to perform `std::move` on `std::optional<std::vector<int>>`?. It's not giving me any compiler or runtime error, but would like to know whether this is valid. This is my sample code snippet.

```
std::optional<std::vector<int>> from;
// do computation...
auto to = std::move(from);
// do computation...
```

Comment: Can you share why you are concerned that isn't valid? It would help understand how to best answer your question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't think `std::optional` has move constructor or move assignment operator taking rvalue references as paramter.

Comment: `std::optional<T>` has a perfectly good move constructor, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional, number 3.  You'll end up with `to` containing the data of the vector, and `from` containing an empty vector.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for that. I thought its just a normal `struct` with no `move constructor` and `move assignment operator` member functions.

Comment: @Harry You don't need to define a custom move constructor or move assignment operator to have move semantics. The compiler generates those for you, as long as you don't do anything to prevent it. See [Are move constructors produced automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283589/are-move-constructors-produced-automatically). "Normal structs" can have move semantics as well. Edit : [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/ha944cf4P).

Comment: Since `std::vector` is moveable then `std::optional<std::vector<int>>` is movable too. Anyway `std::move` doesn't do anything, just do casting of type to make it r-value. So this can't break anything unless later you are using `from`. `auto to = std::move(*from);` is more interesting case.

Comment: @MarekR after `std::move`, is `from` still initialized? I mean the `bool` flag inside `std::optional` struct still `true`?

Comment: @Harry The link provided by Nate Eldredge contains that information : *"[...]  does not make other empty: a moved-from optional still contains a value, but the value itself is moved from."*

Comment: @Harry optional do not become empty, but vector do: https://godbolt.org/z/GhYbKq6ez